# How to make the figure look clear after smoothing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, smoothing, contourf

I make a plot using `pcolormesh` and it turns out like this:

[image]

Then, I tried to set the argument `shading = 'gouraud'`, but the result looks blurry:

[image]

To make the picture clear, I also tried to `interpolate` the data to a smaller meshgrid. Unfortunately, it doesn' work.

So I want to know what I should do to make my plot looks smoother and clearer.

Comment: Do you really need `pcolormesh`? Your data looks like a regular grid, for which `imshow` might be a better option. If so, see:  
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html

Comment: Hi, Rutger. Thanks for your comment. I tried your method but the picture is still unclear. Then I tried to first filter the data using a gaussian filter and it looks smoother! I will post the result and hope it helps. Thanks for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use a gaussian filter to smooth the data and make the plot look clearer.

First, plot the original data, `plt.pcolormesh(x, Y, Z)`, and the result shows:

[image]

Then, let the data pass through a gaussian filter `Z2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(Z, sigma=1.0, order=0)`. And plot the result `plt.contourf(X, Y, Z2, levels = 10)` to give:

[image]

This would make the figure look clear while capturing the main distribution features of the data.

Hope it helps!